# jQuery Mobile template

Tags: jquery-mobile

I don't see what I'm doing wrong here - I'm trying to create a baseline jQuery mobile template.  Looking at the css panel in Firefox, there's no css being rendered.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="author" content="Phillip Senn">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>jQuery Mobile template</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.css">
<script>
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="myPage">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>jQuery Mobile Template</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" id="myContent"> 
        My Content 
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Copyright &copy; 2012 Your name here</h4>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It's just not rendering as a jQuery mobile page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code looks fine, I think it's a problem with the latest jQM builds

- http://jsfiddle.net/ArGXg/1 (using latest linked libraries)
- http://jsfiddle.net/ArGXg/4 (using 1.0 released linked libraries)

Latest Linked Libraries

- http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.css
- http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.js

1.0 Release Linked Libraries

- http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css
- http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js

Note:

Also jQM does not support jQuery verison 1.7.1 yet

- http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js

used 1.6.4

- http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js
- http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js

Comment: Yeah!  I suspected as much because I was looking at the timestamp in the jQuery source, but I just couldn't bring myself to believe it.

Comment: This has happened twice now, where a new version of jQuery (or jQuery Mobile) has broken what I've been working on.  I want to use the latest release, but ...

Comment: I think for jQm the latest version is what ever they're are working on implementing and might not work all the time